# PHP sqlsrv_connect returning false, but no errors

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, sqlsrv, windows-server-2019

As the title suggests I'm trying to connect to an SQL database (which has been working for years) and has suddenly stopped working. I'm using PHP and I've created a little test PHP file which literally just tries to connect.

All I get when connecting is a false object, and sqlsrv_errors contains nothing. PHP code is:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
sqlsrv_configure("WarningsReturnAsErrors", 0);

$server = "*redacted*";
$connectionInfo = array( "database"=>"*redacted*", "UID"=>"*redacted*","PWD"=>"*redacted*");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(),true));
} else {
    print("Worked");
}
?>
```

I don't believe anyone has changed anything but I've since updated the PHP/SQL Driver versions to try and get it working.

I've checked the SQL login by going in directly etc and the server is running on the default port.

All I get back is a blank response (assuming because the sqlsrv_errors are empty)

[image: screenshot of blank response with status 200]

Environment Details:
Website/php is running on IIS on Windows Server 2019
PHP v8.2.10, SQL Driver v5.11 (php_sqlsrv_82_nts_x64)

The SQL server is remote (but on the same subnet/lan) I've tried via IP and name to make sure it's not dns.

To add a few more things I've tried:

- Print "Couldn't connect" before the die - this did print out, so it's getting that far.
- turned firewall off on remote and local servers.
- enabled error reporting on everywhere I can think of in php.ini and in the code

Comment: Are all those parameters really empty? I mean `$server` and `$connectionInfo`

Comment: no, redacted for security..

Comment: @ajp8868: better use values like `"*redacted*"` then, it will give you better feedback, especially with this question as you're asking about troubleshooting -- not adding more troubles ;)

Comment: Except as this issue is about making (or not making) a connection if you redact all the useful information, you are basically asking us to play 20 questions or make a few guesses

Comment: @RiggsFolly redacting our server name and username/password is not going to change the issue at hand - I know for a fact that they are correct :)

Comment: I meant that only for secrets, for a server-name and similar, it should be clear whether a name or ip address or in general the type of address and similar for database (if it's a name), those values can be redacted w/o hiding their value, while for a secret, like a password, you should not on the internet (therefore the suggestion). Yes, writing a good question is hard ^^. And read what @RiggsFolly commented. Always try to read your own question like you're a by-surfing SO user.

Comment: If everything is right, then it could be that from where you are doing this you cannot actually get to where the database is actually located. But of course we cannot even guess from the question if the DB is local or remote

Comment: The vendor documentation (_"How to: Configure Error and Warning Handling Using the SQLSRV Driver"_) suggests in an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-configure-error-and-warning-handling-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver16#example) to `echo "Could not connect.\n";` before such a die(...). This makes sense, as given sqlsrv_errors() returns null, false or an empty string, print_r() would output nothing (as you describe), but the documented behaviour is that false alone means that it could not connect. So you will not run into the "no output" situation.

Comment: Could it be as simple as `array( "database"=>"*redacted*",` should be `array( "Database"=>"*redacted*",`

Comment: I don't believe it's the code. It was working fine, no code or configuration changes (that I know of) have been made before it stopped working. I believe it's more likely to be something within the Windows, SQL or IIS environment config..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. this is not what I expected it to be.

Turns out we had removed "Domain Users" from the "Users" group within computer management on the server running IIS. IIS is using pass thru authentication so I would guess this is why - even though the actual scripts were using SQL authentication.

Re-adding the Domain Users group has fixed it.

Comment: @ajp8868: Don't forget to mark your answer as the answer so that it's visible it has been answered. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry it wouldn't let me do it for a few days :)